# React-Native: Undefined is not an object although there is a decleration in front

Tags: javascript, ios, error-handling, download, react-native

In the following Code I have downloaded a JSON file.
Afterwards I take an Array of Dictionaries of it an passed it to downloadWebsiteData().
In this function it comes following Error:

> Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'web files.length')

Here is my code I am using: **IMPORTANT: webFiles is an Array!**

```
downloadWebsiteData(webFiles) {


    this.setState({amountOfAllWebsites: webFiles.length});

    for(var ii = 0; ii < webFiles.length; ii++)
    {

      var urlToDownload = webFiles[ii].url;

      fetch(urlToDownload, {method: "GET"}).then((responseData) => {

          this.saveDataToLocalStorage(responseData, urlToDownload);
          alert('Save: '+urlToDownload);

          this.setState({actuallyLoadedWebsites: this.state.actuallyLoadedWebsites++});

          this.downloadWebsiteData();

      })
      .done();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at this line `this.downloadWebsiteData();` inside the `fetch` method in the code above. You are not passing any argument to the function `downloadWebsiteData()`. You need to pass in the list of links to the function there if you are intending to call it recursively.